# Android webview error when asking for geolocation

Tags: android, webview, geolocation, android-permissions

I'm getting the user geolocation with getCurrentPosition and it's working fine in Google Chrome, But in Android Webview i get this error:

> E/cr_LocationProvider: Caught security exception while registering for
>   location updates from the system. The application does not have
>   sufficient geolocation permissions. E/cr_LocationProvider:
>   newErrorAvailable application does not have sufficient geolocation
>   permissions.

This is my Manifast:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="il.co.example.example">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/example_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/example_icon_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></manifest>
```

And This is my MainActivity:
    package il.co.example.example;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

class MyClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                   Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

        // Enable Javascript
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // Enable Geolocation
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);

        // URL for Webview
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        // HTML5 API flags
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                           GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {

                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

What did I miss? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insufficient geolocation permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786733/insufficient-geolocation-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

If your app targets **Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher**, you must declare that your app uses the **android.hardware.location.network or android.hardware.location.gps** hardware feature in the manifest file, depending on whether your app receives location updates from NETWORK_PROVIDER or from GPS_PROVIDER.

If your app receives location information from either of these location provider sources, you need to declare that the app uses these hardware features in your app manifest. On devices running versions prior to Android 5.0 (API 21), requesting the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission includes an implied request for location hardware features. However, requesting those permissions does not automatically request location hardware features on Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher.

The following code sample demonstrates how to declare the permission and hardware feature in the manifest file of an app that reads data from the device's GPS:

```
<manifest ... >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
...
<!-- Needed only if your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />  </manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, my app targets Android 5.0 and higher. I add android.hardware.location.gps and android.hardware.location.network and still got the same error.